# Unit test of Cuda code running on a TeamCity agent

Tags: unit-testing, cuda, teamcity

We have some algorithms optimized using Cuda that we would like to unit test in our automated build system running TeamCity.
Unfortunately the tests fail on the TeamCity agent because cudaGetDeviceCount reports that there are no capable devices. 
I assume it happens because the TeamCity agent cannot access the display but I only want to do computations in the background and no rendering to screen.

Any sugestions? Searching for unit test+Cuda+TeamCity does not yield anything usefull.

Comment: You don't need access to the display to use CUDA. Does your build system have a CUDA-capable device? Is the process running in a sandbox that restricts access to the GPU?

Comment: It turned out that Windows power management was configured to turn off the display after 20mins and that makes the test run fail. So when I set Windows to keep the display always on then it works.

Comment: @logicnet.dk: If you found a solution to this problem, could you add a short answer, just to get the question off the unanswered queue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that Windows power management was configured to turn off the display after 20mins and that makes the test run fail. So when I set Windows to keep the display always on then it works.